# Preference has wrong value when rebuilding PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android, oncreate, rebuild, preferencefragment

I am creating several Color Picker preferences (extended from Preference) in the onCreate method of my Preference Fragment.

The colorpickers describe the current design that is active. So when the user picks a new design (in the same PreferenceFragment) all color pickers have to change according to the new design.

For this I am getting the new color values of the current design and rebuild the PreferenceFragment

```
public static void RebuildSettings() {

colorFieldList = GetNewColorFields();

if (mPrefsFragment != null) {

    mPrefsFragment.onDestroy();
    mPrefsFragment.onCreate(null);

} else Log.i(Patterns.TAG, "mPrefsFragment = null");

}
```

In the onCreate method of my Preference Fragment I then recreate the color fields from colorFieldList (with the colors from new design) like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    [...]

PreferenceCategory colorSettings = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("prefCat_ColorSettings");

    for (int i = 0; i < colorFieldList.size(); i++) {

        AmbilWarnaPreference colorPicker = new AmbilWarnaPreference(getActivity(), null);
        colorPicker.forceSetValue(colorFieldList.get(i).color);
        colorPicker.setTitle(colorFieldList.get(i).name);
        colorPicker.setSummary("Set color in " + colorFieldList.get(i).name);
        colorPicker.setKey("colorField" + colorFieldList.get(i).index);
        colorPicker.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(colorListener);

        if (colorSettings != null)
            colorSettings.addPreference(colorPicker);

    }

    [...]
}
```

Now I can change the designs and the color fields will update fine according to the new design **BUT only when I have not changed any color picker field yet**.
The fields change like they are supposed to but **as soon as I change a color field / pick a new color, this field forever stays the color I chose**, although I rebuild the settings completely every time the design is changed!

What am I missing? Why are the colors updating as long as no value is saved to SharedPreferences (?) but not after?

I guess android always grabs the value of the color picker from shared preferences once it has been set, but how can I overwrite it in OnCreate to depict the colors from the chosen design?

Your help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Has no one got an idea? :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: Like I assumed the problem was that the items always received the default values for their specific key.

To overwrite this behaviour I had to call Apply() (commit would also work I guess) on the editor in the onCreate() method of my preference fragment like this:

```
getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().edit().putInt("colorField" + colorFieldList.get(i).index, colorFieldList.get(i).color).apply();
```

(I did this in the loop I posted above, so every color preference was assigned to a new color on creation with an overwritten preference value)